# Wiring on RPI3 when connecting two peripherals - microcontrollers simultaneously

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-3b+, connection, peripherals, data-transfer

I am currently having an ADC(MCP3008) connected to a rpi3, using the following wiring map, in order to read data from analog sensors.

```
MCP3008 -> RPI3 
VDD     -> 3.3V  
VREF    -> 3.3V  
AGND    -> GND  
CLK     -> #18  
DOUT    -> #23  
DIN     -> #24  
CS      -> #25  
DGND    -> GND
```

Now what I am trying to do, is to also connect a LoRa RFM95W on the same rpi3, in order to transmit these data to a LoRa Gateway. The wiring for the LoRa node transmitter is the following.

```
RFM95W   -> RPI3  
3.3V     -> #1
GND      -> #6
DI00     -> #7
RST      -> #11
NSS      -> #22
MOSI     -> #19
MISO     -> #21
SCK      -> #23
```

So the two wiring maps seem to have nothing in common except from SCK on RPI pin #23. (And the power which is not a problem).

How should I wire the ADC and the transmitter on pin #23, should I follow that [Daisy-chained SPI bus connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface#Independent_slave_configuration) or should I plug both of them directly on pin #23?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Typical SPI bus: master and three independent slaves.
In this topology you are differentiating the two peripherals with the CS (chip select) line. Not Daisy-chained SPI bus connection.

For a start I would connect the devices to the RPi3 with the pin #23 connected to both, probably it will not work.  The correct solution is a the master and slaves topology.

MCP3008 -> RPI3

VDD     -> 3.3V

VREF    -> 3.3V

AGND    -> GND

CLK     -> #18

DOUT    -> #23

DIN     -> #24

CS      -> #25

DGND    -> GND

RFM95W   -> RPI3

3.3V     -> #1

GND      -> #6

DI00     -> #7

RST      -> #11

NSS      -> #22

MOSI     -> #24

MISO     -> #23

SCK      -> #18

Comment: on the rfm95w you say SCK #1, this is probably a typo ?